# How to break out of continue statement after certain amount of tries?

Tags: python

Apologies if the question to this is worded a bit poorly, but I can't seem to find help on this exercise anywhere. I am writing a basic Python script which sums two numbers together, but if both numbers inputted are the same the sum will not be calculated.

```
while True:
   print('Please enter a number ')
   num1 = input()
   print('Please enter a second number ')
   num2 = input()

   if num1 == num2:
       print('Bingo equal numbers!')
       continue
   elif num1 == num2:
       print('It was fun calculating for you!')
       break
   print('The sum of both numbers is = ' + str(int(num1) + int(num2)))
   break
```

If both numbers are equal I want the script to loop back once more and if the numbers inputted are equal again I want the program to end. With the code I have provided the issue I am having is that when I enter two equal numbers it keeps constantly looping until I enter two different numbers.

Comment: IMO this sounds like a variation of (or is at least very similar to) [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would likely want to have a variable keeping track of the number of times that the numbers were matching.  Then do something if that counter (keeping track of the matching) is over a certain threshold.  Try something like

```
matches = 0
while True:
    num1 = input('Please enter a number: ')
    num2 = input('Please enter a second number: ')

    if num1 == num2 and matches < 1:
        matches += 1
        print('Bingo equal numbers!')
        continue
    elif num1 == num2:
        print('It was fun calculating for you!')
        break
    print('The sum of both numbers is = ' + str(int(num1) + int(num2)))
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add give input code again inside first `if` statement or use some other dummy variable for loop so that you can break the loop, for e.g. use `while j == 0` and increase it `j += 1`when you are inside the first `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

`continue` skips the execution of everything else in the loop. I don't see it much useful in your example. If you want to print the `sum` then just remove it.

How `continue` works can be demonstrated by this sample (taken from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html))

```
for num in range(2, 10):
     if num % 2 == 0:
         print("Found an even number", num)
         continue
     print("Found a number", num)
```

Result

```
Found an even number 2
Found a number 3
Found an even number 4
Found a number 5
Found an even number 6
Found a number 7
Found an even number 8
Found a number 9
```